# ReWriteRule is redirecting rather rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

At the moment I have two machines that I do web development on; an iMac for work at the office and a MacBook for when I have to work on the move. They both running OS X 10.6 have the same version of PHP, Apache, etc  running on them.

Both computers have the same files of the website, including the .htaccess file (see below).  On the MacBook the URLs are rewritten nicely, masking the URL they are pointing to (eg site/page/page-name), however on the iMac they simply redirect to the page (eg site/index.php?method=page&value=page-name) which is making switching back and forth between machines a bit of a pain!

I'm sure it must be a config setting somewhere, but I can't for the life of me find it.  Has anyone got a remedy?  Many thanks.

I'm fairly convinced there is a much nice way of writing this htaccess file without loosing access several key folders as well!

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /In%20Progress/Vila%20Maninga/

RewriteRule ^page/([a-z|0-9_&;=-]+) index.php?method=page&value=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^tag/([a-z|0-9_]+) index.php?method=tag&value=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/([a-z|0-9_"]+) index.php?method=search&value=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^modpage/([con0-9-]+) index.php?method=modpage&value=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^login index.php?method=login [NC]
RewriteRule ^logout index.php?method=logout [NC]
RewriteRule ^useraccounts index.php?method=useraccounts [NC]
```

Comment: Is the server configuration the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to ensure the `MultiViews` directive is disabled, as it may be causing this.

Comment: Interestingly the server config was identical (it got to the stage where I literally copy and pasted it across).  However the modification to MultiViews sorted it out on the iMac.

Many thanks Kristopher and Gumbo